# Add Gradle to a project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a project that was built using IntelliJ Idea originally now I am working on this project in android studio and want to use gradle in the project.

I need help regarding this as I am clueless as to how this can be done with an existing project in Android studio. I tried looking for some similar answers but none solved my problem.

Do I manually need to make `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`? If yes what exactly to add in these files and where to implement them in my project. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my project folder with all folders and files. [Root Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cE8F.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to import this project (File | New | Import project...)? Appears the clean solution to me instead of manually fiddling around with gradle config files.

Comment: Yes  I tried that but it didn't do anything, should this step add gradle files on its own? @TAM

Comment: Also I tried this and whenever i try to import this way it automatically creates .idea and .iml files again on it's own which are no longer required.